# How to format months in german and minus one month

Tags: php, date, strtotime, setlocale

My problem is that I only want the current month to be formatted in *German* and that unfortunately doesn't work with my progress so far. But additionally the month should be displayed in *German* and always -1 (so instead of December it would now be November). What is the easiest way to do this, and why can't I do it over `setlocale`?

Thank you in advance :)

Here's my code:

```
<?php
setlocale (LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'de', 'ge');
echo $newdate = date("m.Y", strtotime("-1 months"));
?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php: _“To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and strftime() functions instead of date().”_

Comment: [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) with the `DateTimeZone` set ... I find `setlocale` *unreliable* - especially on a Windows dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

Okay have found a solution from php.net..

```
<?php
//showing Dates in German lanuage:
function formatDateString($stamp) {
    //initalise String:
  //Gettting the months set up...
                $monate = array(1=>"Januar",
                2=>"Februar",
                3=>"M&auml;rz",
                4=>"April",
                5=>"Mai",
                6=>"Juni",
                7=>"Juli",
                8=>"August",
                9=>"September",
                10=>"Oktober",
                11=>"November",
                12=>"Dezember");

  //Getting our Month
                $monat = date("n", strtotime("-1 months"));

    //Getting the Days set up....
                $tage = array("Sonntag","Montag","Dienstag","Mittwoch",
                    "Donnerstag","Freitag","Samstag");

$printme = $monate[$monat];

return $printme;
}
```

and added strtotime("-1 months") to get a month earlier

But thanks for fast help :)